# Automate the Boring Stuff: Comma Code : Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Tags: python

```
animals = ["rat", "cat", "bat", "mouse", "zebra", "barbeque", "chicken"]
def joiner(joined):
    while True:
        if len(joined) == 0:
            break
        else:
            lister = ", ".join(joined[:-1])
            lister = lister + " and " + joined[-1]
            print(lister)
            break             

joiner(animals)
```

This is the code I have which will take in a list and return a string separated by commas with a "and" separating the last two. Was there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: That `while True` is completely pointless.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: Please provide references to the problem you are trying to solve (e.g. book, chapter, …) so others can attempt it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that all the existing answers change the OPs code structurally, if not behaviorally.  This, I believe, does not:

```
animals = ["rat", "cat", "bat", "mouse", "zebra", "barbeque", "chicken"]

def joiner(x):
    if x:
        print(', '.join(x[0:-1]) + " and " + x[-1])

joiner(animals)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first join then replace the last instance of the comma with "and". This is robust enough to accept multiple delimiters and not just commas.

For example:

```
animals = ["rat", "cat", "bat", "mouse", "zebra", "barbeque", "chicken"]

def addand(list_to_use, char_to_find):

    base_string = ','.join(list_to_use)
    k = base_string .rfind(char_to_find)
    new_string = animals_string[:k] + " and " + animals_string[k+1:]
    return new_string



 new_string = addand(animals, ',')
```

Output:

```
rat,cat,bat,mouse,zebra,barbeque and chicken
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

One liner that beautifies cases of 0 and 1 elements:

```
'sorry, empty list' if len(animals)==0 else animals[0] if len(animals)==1  else ", ".join(animals[:-1]) + " and " + animals[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to special case for length = 0, 1, and 2.  But the general case is:

```
', '.join(x[0:-1]) + ", and " + x[-1]
```

I prefer the serial comma.  If you're not, change `", and "` to `" and "` and don't bother special casing length == 2.

Comment: But it is shorter, thus more efficient, which is what i was looking for

Comment: Actually, it's not true that this does the same thing as the OP's code.  Look more closely....in fact, I see two differences.

Comment: @Haris_Mauler - It's not always true that shorter code is more efficient (I'm not saying that this isn't), because, for instance, loading and using an external module for something could be shorter than writing slightly longer code to do the same without the module, but the latter might be more efficient. This obviously depends on the case though.

Comment: This adds an oxford comma to the list, even though OP's code does not. Also differs from OP's algo for cases when len(list) < 2

Comment: @Steve.  Oops, missed that original poster didn't want the Oxford comma.   Will fix

Answer (score 0):

```
def joiner_new(joined):
  if len(joined) > 1:
    joined = joined[:-2] + [joined[-2] + " and " + joined[-1]]
  print(", ".join(joined))
joiner_new(animals)
```

Comment: What about when joined == [] ?

Comment: Adding a bit of explanation for the code and why you think it's a good solution would be helpful--this was flagged as low quality for being code-only.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't wasteful in terms of operations it performs, but if you want to make it look shorter you can do this:

```
animals = ["rat", "cat", "bat", "mouse", "zebra", "barbeque", "chicken"]
def joiner(joined):
    try:
        lister = ', '.join(joined[:-1] + ['and ' + joined[-1]])
        print(lister)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```